# Пустой результат выполнения скрипта SQL

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат выполнения `print(param_s.execute('SELECT respawn FROM spawn_point'))` на второй строке в `output -> []`.
Я не понимаю по какой причине это происходит, если в таблицу успешно загружаются данные с помощью того же метода `execute()`.

```py
    def execute(self, script: str):
        try:
            self.__cursor.executescript(script)
            result = self.__cursor.fetchall()
            self.__db_connection.commit()
            return result
        except Exception as err:
            print(f'{err} in {__class__.__name__} -> {self.execute.__name__}')
```

[Полный код тут](https://pastebin.com/eNG97jux)

Comment: Приведите код, достаточно полный для того, чтобы воспроизвести вашу проблему

Comment: @andreymal, https://pastebin.com/eNG97jux

Comment: В executescript не предусмотрено никакого возвращения никаких данных, используйте execute